# Using UITableView and IndexPath with Swift 3 shows an error

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have this code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: IndexPath) as? Cell
```

But IndexPath is showing an error:

[image]

Comment: I believe it's because you're referencing the class, not the variable. Try switching `IndexPath` to `indexPath`.

Comment: @JodyHeavener That's interesting. I used autocomplete for `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` and it added `IndexPath`. So I just copied it. Let me try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: IndexPath) as? Cell
```

In this line you're passing `IndexPath` Class instead of the `indexPath` parameter from the function. replace it with:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell
```